# What is difference between @ImportAutoConfiguration and @Import

Tags: spring-boot, spring-java-config

Is it true that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration` is improved replacement for `org.springframework.context.annotation.Import` because does the same and additionally respects

`@AutoConfigureBefore`, `@AutoConfigureAfter` and `@AutoConfigureOrder` ?

Answer (score 10):

> Is it true that
>   `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration` is
>   improved replacement for
>   `org.springframework.context.annotation.Import`?

No it is not a replacement since `@ImportAutoConfiguration` is a Spring Boot specific annotation, I might call it an enhancement. But eventhough it seems that you can use them interchangeably when using Spring Boot, I wouldn't suggest it. Use them as they were intended to be used.

---

You would use `@ImportAutoConfiguration` when you don't want to enable the default autoconfiguration with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. As you probably know, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` attemps to configure beans that are located on your classpath eg tomcat-embedded.jar. Whereas `@ImportAutoConfiguration` only runs the configuration classes that you provided in the annotation.

This is an example of an Spring Boot application main method with `@ImportAutoConfiguration`:

```
@ComponentScan("path.to.your.controllers")
@ImportAutoConfiguration({WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class
    , DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class
    , EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class
    , ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class
    , HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

You might say that it is an alternative to using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. And in this case to configure barebone embedded Tomcat and Spring WebMVC.

---

`@Import` is used to import a bean configuration class marked with `@Configuration` which contains your custom bean configurations.

Comment: Assume I have application App which is provided as example here. What will change if I replace 'ImportAutoConfiguration' by 'Import'?

Comment: I tried it out with `@Import` and nothing changed. All the beans are created and all configuration is performed.

Comment: I'm actually also interested what the real technical difference is between using the two annotations.

Comment: So what exactly is an autoconfiguration class? I mean what does a `@Configuration` class need to have to be considered an autoconfiguration class which should be imported by `@ImportAutoConfiguration` instead of `@Import`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the source code of both annotations? The interface definitions already give away how they are similar and how they differ. As of today, the `@Import` annotation is defined like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Import {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

Whereas the `@ImportAutoConfiguration` annotation is defined like that:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Import({ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector.class})
public @interface ImportAutoConfiguration {
    @AliasFor("classes")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor("value")
    Class<?>[] classes() default {};

    Class<?>[] exclude() default {};
}
```

As you can see, they have a lot in common. However, the `@ImportAutoConfiguration` annotation has an additional alias for `value` that is called `classes`. Moreover, it supports a property to `exclude` classes.

Also notice the additional `@Import` of the `ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector` class.

Comment: thank you for effort, but I wanted to know difference in result and suggestion when to use each other, not difference in source code.