# When to use @ImportAutoConfiguration vs @Import

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The docs aren't very clear to me on when to use one vs. the other. They both seem to have the same behavior from the things I've tried. What's the difference exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between @ImportAutoConfiguration and @Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653655/what-is-difference-between-importautoconfiguration-and-import)

Comment: @ShekharRai No, because as discussed in the comments on the one answer there, they also are still questioning what the actual fundamental difference between the two are :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, **@Import** annotation imports the one or more **@Configuration** classes and those classes may declare one or more **@Bean** methods.

Whereas, **@ImportAutoConfiguration** annotation imports and applies the specified auto-configuration classes.

> More detailed comparison over **@Import** and **@ImportAutoConfiguration**

## @Import

- Indicates one or more component classes to import — typically @Configuration classes.
- It's an annotation from `spring-context` module
- A simple example, let's say you have these configuration classes,

  **UserConfig**

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class UserConfig {

      @Bean(name="user")
      public User userConfigure(){                
          return new User();              
      }
  }
  ```

  **SchedulerConfig**

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class SchedulerConfig {

      @Bean(name="scheduler")
      public Schedule cheduleConfigure(){             
          return new Schedule();              
      }
  }
  ```

  **AppConfig**

  Import those configuration classes using @Import annotation

  ```
  @Configuration
  @Import({ UserConfig.class, SchedulerConfig.class })
  public class AppConfig {

  }
  ```

## @ImportAutoConfiguration

- Import and apply the specified [auto-configuration classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-auto-configuration-classes.html).
- It's an annotation from the spring-boot-autoconfigure module.
- It represents a way to automatically configure a Spring application based on the dependencies that are present on the classpath.
- Since it's from `spring-boot` module - you can only use this annotation in `Spring-Boot applications`
- It can be useful especially when writing tests.
- A simple example,

  As in the @Import section, we need to create class annotated with @Configuration here as well. Unlike on the above @Import example, you can use different `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition`s (ConditionalOnProperty, ConditionalOnResource, ConditionalOnBean, ConditionalOnMissingBean etc) on your `auto-configuration` class.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.data.base.config", name = "enable", havingValue = "true")
  public class DataAutoConfiguration {

      @Bean
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.data.base")
      public DataService dataService() {
          return new DataService();
      }
  }
  ```

  Import auto-configuration using @ImportAutoConfiguration annotation

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ImportAutoConfiguration(DataAutoConfiguration.class)
  public class MyDatabaseAutoconfiguration {
      //...
  }
  ```

  Now you need register it in `resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file,

  ```
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.your.package.autoconfiguration.MyDatabaseAutoconfiguration
  ```

  To enable auto-configuration, we can use one of the **@SpringBootApplication** or **@EnableAutoConfiguration annotations**

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class AutoconfigurationApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(AutoconfigurationApplication.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```

## Some more references

- [ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)
- [ConditionalOnResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnResource.html)
- [ConditionalOnBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html)
- [ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html)
- [spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration)
- [using-boot-auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-auto-configuration)

Comment: So is the major difference that `@ImportAutoConfiguration` would only be evaluated properly when `@ConditionalOnProperty ` is used?

Comment: Hmm somehow yes! But you have multiple conditionals as I provided in reference section - you can use either of them or multiple of them..

Comment: Another important difference is  `@ImportAutoConfiguration` will *only* process the AutoConfiguration classes explicitly imported. The `META-INF/spring.factories` will be ignored when you do this.

Comment: You are saying `@Import` won't consider the `@Conditional[...]` annotations on the specified configuration class. But what about `@Conditional`. This comes from spring-context and not from Spring Boot.

Comment: @ImportAutoConfiguration support exclude

Comment: `@Import` and `@ImportAutoConfiguration` don't agree on load order, as I understand it, which affects whether an auto configuration class with a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean @Bean` factory supplies a bean or not. If you use `@Import`, the imported class is loaded before your annotated configuration class, so it will always provide `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` beans regardless of whether your annotated class provides any. You have to use `@ImportAutoConfiguration` to ensure the auto configuration is overridden by the annotated class.